# Edit errors on login and lost password screen in wordpress

Tags: php

Does anyone know a way to edit the wordpress errors that appear on the registration screen and lost passwords screen:

Lost password screen error
ERROR: Enter a username or email address.

Registration screen error:
ERROR: Please type your email address.

Thanks :-)

Comment: read the wp-login.php file. If you can change anything you'll see the filters in there (ie. apply_filters())

Answer (score 0):

you can change the message in login screen by using login_errors filter hook, just paste this code in the themes functions.php file :

```
add_filter('login_errors','login_error_message');

function login_error_message($error){
     //check if that's the error you are looking for
     $pos = strpos($error, 'incorrect');
     if (is_int($pos)) {
         //its the right error so you can overwrite it
         $error = "Wrong information";
     }
     return $error;
}
```

for registration screen error refer this codex page 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/registration_errors